# Randomly generating a latlng within a radius yields a point out of bounds

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to generate a point within a radius and I'm getting incorrect values. Someone mind taking a look and telling me what I'm doing wrong for the longitude? This was a formulaic approach posted on a different question...

```
  public static Location generateLocationWithinRadius(Location myCurrentLocation) {
    return getLocationInLatLngRad(1000, myCurrentLocation);
}

protected static Location getLocationInLatLngRad(double radiusInMeters, Location currentLocation) {
    double x0 = currentLocation.getLatitude();
    double y0 = currentLocation.getLongitude();

    Random random = new Random();

    // Convert radius from meters to degrees
    double radiusInDegrees = radiusInMeters / 111000f;

    double u = random.nextDouble();
    double v = random.nextDouble();
    double w = radiusInDegrees * Math.sqrt(u);
    double t = 2 * Math.PI * v;
    double x = w * Math.cos(t);
    double y = w * Math.sin(t);

    double new_x = x / Math.cos(y0);
    double new_y = y / Math.cos(x0);
    double foundLatitude;
    double foundLongitude;
    boolean shouldAddOrSubtractLat = random.nextBoolean();
    boolean shouldAddOrSubtractLon = random.nextBoolean();
    if (shouldAddOrSubtractLat) {
        foundLatitude = new_x + x0;
    } else {
        foundLatitude = x0 - new_x;
    }
    if (shouldAddOrSubtractLon) {
        foundLongitude = new_y + y0;
    } else {
        foundLongitude = y0 - new_y;
    }
    Location copy = new Location(currentLocation);
    copy.setLatitude(foundLatitude);
    copy.setLongitude(foundLongitude);
    return copy;
}
```

I should also say that for some reason the valid points yield a uniform line of coordinates when looking at them.

I think the latitude is processing correctly whereas the longitude is not.

Comment: Show your input, output and expected output.

Comment: I should also say that I'm using static values right now but I'm going to keep them adjustable and reduce the amount of pointers

Comment: lat lng varies very much in terms of decimal places. So random value that you are generating should  differ in 0.000x range  if they are bounded in a radius.

Comment: Currently the latitude does so but the longitude does not do so properly. If I just hold to altering the latitude values, the points are distributed in a straight latitudinal line which is acceptable, but I would prefer the points to be scattered as far as longitude goes. I'm thinking a max/min would do the trick.

Comment: Can you please specify what Location class is? I assume it is a (latitude, longitude) pair of doubles but I would like to make sure.

Comment: It is the standard Android location class. It encapsulates a latitude, longitude, and altitude for the purpose it is required here.

Comment: Direct mapping from degrees to meters only works (pretty well) for the latitude as the latitude lines are all (pretty much) at the same distance from each other. The mapping from degrees of longitude to meters varies depending on the latitude. At the equator the degrees to meters behaves (pretty much) like the latitude and at the north and south pole the distance between any longitude values is always 0 meters. So the relation of degrees and the actual distance on the earth's surface changes when moving north/south. Not everything previously posted to Stack Overflow always works perfectly.

Comment: I could do with longitude having an approximation so long as it's not hundreds of meters off. Preferably no more than 10 meters off.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Your code seems to be more or less based on an idea 
[which is presented at gis.stackexchange.com](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25877/how-to-generate-random-locations-nearby-my-location/) 
and discussed some more there in [this discussion](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/69328/generate-random-location-within-specified-distance-of-a-given-point) 
and in [this discussion](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/186135/generating-random-points-near-a-location).

If we take a closer look at it based on those discussions then maybe it makes more sense.

To easily limit the values to a circle it uses the approach of randomizing a direction and a distance. First we get two random double values between 0.0 ... 1.0:

```java
double u = random.nextDouble();
double v = random.nextDouble();
```

As the radius is given in meters and the calculations require degrees, it's converted:

```java
double radiusInDegrees = radiusInMeters / 111000f;
```

The degrees vs. meters ratio of the equator is used here. (Wikipedia suggests 111320 m.)

To have a more uniform distribution of the random points the distance is compensated with a square root:

```java
w = r * sqrt(u)
```

Otherwise there would be a statistical bias in the amount of points near the center vs. far from the center. The square root of 1 is 1 and 0 of course 0, so 
multiplying the root of the random double by the intended max. radius always gives a value between 0 and the radius.

Then the other random double is multiplied by 2 * pi because there are 2 * pi radians in a full circle:

```java
t = 2 * Pi * v
```

We now have an angle somewhere between 0 ... 2 * pi i.e. 0 ... 360 degrees.

Then the random x and y coordinate deltas are calculated with basic trigonometry using the random distance and random angle:

```java
x = w * cos(t) 
y = w * sin(t)
```

The `[x,y]` then points some random distance `w` away from the original coordinates towards the direction `t`.

Then the varying distance between longitude lines is compensated with trigonometry (`y0` being the center's y coordinate):

```java
x' = x / cos(y0)
```

Above `y0` needs to be converted to radians if the `cos()` expects the angle as radians. In Java it does.

It's then suggested that these delta values are added to the original coordinates. The `cos` and `sin` are negative for half of the full circle's angles so just adding is fine. Some of the random points will be to the west from Greenwich and and south from the equator. There's no need to randomize 
should an addition or subtraction be done.

So the random point would be at `(x'+x0, y+y0)`.

I don't know why your code has:

```java
double new_y = y / Math.cos(x0);
```

And like said we can ignore `shouldAddOrSubtractLat` and `shouldAddOrSubtractLon`.

In my mind `x` refers to something going from left to right or from west to east. That's how the longitude values grow even though the longitude lines go from south to north. So let's use `x` as longitude and `y` as latitude.

So what's left then? Something like:

```java
protected static Location getLocationInLatLngRad(double radiusInMeters, Location currentLocation) {
    double x0 = currentLocation.getLongitude();
    double y0 = currentLocation.getLatitude();

    Random random = new Random();

    // Convert radius from meters to degrees.
    double radiusInDegrees = radiusInMeters / 111320f;

    // Get a random distance and a random angle.
    double u = random.nextDouble();
    double v = random.nextDouble();
    double w = radiusInDegrees * Math.sqrt(u);
    double t = 2 * Math.PI * v;
    // Get the x and y delta values.
    double x = w * Math.cos(t);
    double y = w * Math.sin(t);

    // Compensate the x value.
    double new_x = x / Math.cos(Math.toRadians(y0));

    double foundLatitude;
    double foundLongitude;

    foundLatitude = y0 + y;
    foundLongitude = x0 + new_x;

    Location copy = new Location(currentLocation);
    copy.setLatitude(foundLatitude);
    copy.setLongitude(foundLongitude);
    return copy;
}
```

Comment: One of the best answers ever given on SOF!

Comment: What is that 'f' means? in this line.

//    double radiusInDegrees = radiusInMeters / 111320f;

Comment: It means 111320 is a floating point number.

Answer (score 2):

Kotlin version of [Markus Kauppinen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36919707/9502867) answer

```
fun Location.getRandomLocation(radius: Double): Location {
    val x0: Double = longitude
    val y0: Double = latitude

    // Convert radius from meters to degrees.

    // Convert radius from meters to degrees.
    val radiusInDegrees: Double = radius / 111320f

    // Get a random distance and a random angle.

    // Get a random distance and a random angle.
    val u = Random.nextDouble()
    val v = Random.nextDouble()
    val w = radiusInDegrees * sqrt(u)
    val t = 2 * Math.PI * v
    // Get the x and y delta values.
    // Get the x and y delta values.
    val x = w * cos(t)
    val y = w * sin(t)

    // Compensate the x value.

    // Compensate the x value.
    val newX = x / cos(Math.toRadians(y0))

    val foundLatitude: Double
    val foundLongitude: Double

    foundLatitude = y0 + y
    foundLongitude = x0 + newX

    val copy = Location(this)
    copy.latitude = foundLatitude
    copy.longitude = foundLongitude
    return copy
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is hard for me to provide you with a pure Android solution as I never used those API. However I am sure you could easily adapt this solution to generate a random point within a given radius from an existing point.

The problem is solved in a two dimensions space however it is easy to extend to support altitude as well.

Please have a look at the code below. It provides you with a `LocationGenerator`as well as my own `Location` implementation and an unit test proving that it works.

My solution is based on solving the circle equation `(x-a)^2 + (y-b)^2 = r^2`

```
package my.test.pkg;

import org.junit.Test;

import java.util.Random;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;

public class LocationGeneratorTest {
    private class Location {
        double longitude;
        double latitude;

        public Location(double longitude, double latitude) {
            this.longitude = longitude;
            this.latitude = latitude;
        }
    }

    private class LocationGenerator {
        private final Random random = new Random();

        Location generateLocationWithinRadius(Location currentLocation, double radius) {
            double a = currentLocation.longitude;
            double b = currentLocation.latitude;
            double r = radius;

            // x must be in (a-r, a + r) range
            double xMin = a - r;
            double xMax = a + r;
            double xRange = xMax - xMin;

            // get a random x within the range
            double x = xMin + random.nextDouble() * xRange;

            // circle equation is (y-b)^2 + (x-a)^2 = r^2
            // based on the above work out the range for y
            double yDelta = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(r,  2) - Math.pow((x - a), 2));
            double yMax = b + yDelta;
            double yMin = b - yDelta;
            double yRange = yMax - yMin;
            // Get a random y within its range
            double y = yMin + random.nextDouble() * yRange;

            // And finally return the location
            return new Location(x, y);
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void shoulRandomlyGeneratePointWithinRadius () throws Exception {
        LocationGenerator locationGenerator = new LocationGenerator();
        Location currentLocation = new Location(20., 10.);
        double radius = 5.;
        for (int i=0; i < 1000000; i++) {
            Location randomLocation = locationGenerator.generateLocationWithinRadius(currentLocation, radius);
            try {
                assertTrue(Math.pow(randomLocation.latitude - currentLocation.latitude, 2) + Math.pow(randomLocation.longitude - currentLocation.longitude, 2) < Math.pow(radius, 2));
            } catch (Throwable e) {
                System.out.println("i= " + i + ", x=" + randomLocation.longitude + ", y=" + randomLocation.latitude);
                throw new Exception(e);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

**NOTE:**
This is just a generic solution to obtain a random point inside a circle with the center in (a, b) and a radius of r that can be used to solve your problem and not a straight solution that you can use as such. You most likely will need to adapt it to your use case.

I believe this is a natural solution.

Regards

Comment: What unit should I use for the radius? I tried Meters and Kilometers but I'm getting very high distances between my current location and the location that procures.

Comment: The radius apparently has to be in degrees as it's added to/subtracted from a longitude value that's in degrees. So it would have to converted from meters to degrees to call the function. I wonder what's the implication of the angle/meters ratio changing in north-south direction in these calculations. (Maybe it works just fine. I didn't check.)

Comment: @KoalaKoalified in my algorithm I did not attached any concept of distance unit., They are just three double values: longitude, latitude, radius. When I implemented it my assumption was that they they are just lengths all expressed with the same unit. Depending on your use case you can express in meters or Km. If your code uses degrees I don't think it will be any problem to convert them in meters or Km depending on your needs 
Keep in mind that my Location class was just a made up to get the generator work and could be very different than the Location you are using.

Comment: I am sure there are lots of scientific places you can take the right conversion formulas from. Here are just two of them:
[here](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) or [here](http://www.uwgb.edu/dutchs/UsefulData/UTMFormulas.HTM)
It seems to be quite complex I would be surprised not to have some java APIs that do this already.

Answer (score 0):

Longitude and Latitude uses ellipsoidal coordinates so for big radius (hundred meters) the error using this method would become sinificant. A possible trick is to convert to Cartesian coordinates, do the radius randomization and then transform back again to ellipsoidal coordinates for the long-lat. I have tested this up to a couple of kilometers with great success using [this java library](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-coordconvert/) from ibm. Longer than that might work, but eventually the radius would fall off as the earth shows its spherical nature.